# d3.js function to count data belonging to a category and bigger than 0

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, d3.js, count

I am trying to create a function that counts the people of each category that have a value bigger than 0. If this is my data...

```
DATA.CSV
name; category; value
name1; A; 10
name2; A; 0
name3; A; 5
name4; B; 7
name5; B; 3
name6; C; 0
```

...I should get the following results

```
count(dataset, "A")=2
count(dataset, "B")=2
count(dataset, "C")=0
```

EDIT! I am actually loading data from a .json file

```
 [
  {
    "voce":"amministrazione",
    "categoria":"funzioni",
    "val2015":404571081
  },
  {
    "voce":"sociale",
    "categoria":"funzioni",
    "val2015":235251679
  },
  {
    "voce":"territorio e ambiente",
    "categoria":"funzioni",
    "val2015":286164667
  },
  {
    "voce":"viabilità e trasporti ",
    "categoria":"funzioni",
    "val2015":144185664
  },
  {
    "voce":"istruzione",
    "categoria":"funzioni",
    "val2015":168774925
  },
  {
    "voce":"cultura ",
    "categoria":"funzioni",
    "val2015":55868045
  },
  {
    "voce":"sport",
    "categoria":"funzioni",
    "val2015":27219432
  },
  {
    "voce":"turismo",
    "categoria":"funzioni",
    "val2015":9544845
  },
  {
    "voce":"sviluppo economico",
    "categoria":"funzioni",
    "val2015":14790363
  },
  {
    "voce":"servizi produttivi",
    "categoria":"funzioni",
    "val2015":4334
  },
  {
    "voce":"polizia locale",
    "categoria":"funzioni",
    "val2015":99007202
  },
  {
    "voce":"giustizia ",
    "categoria":"funzioni",
    "val2015":12147068
  },
  {
    "voce":"anticipazioni di cassa",
    "categoria":"rimborso prestiti",
    "val2015":304323808
  },
  {
    "voce":"finanziamenti a breve termine",
    "categoria":"rimborso prestiti",
    "val2015":0
  },
  {
    "voce":"prestiti obbligazionari",
    "categoria":"rimborso prestiti",
    "val2015":38842996
  },
  {
    "voce":"quota capitale di debiti pluriennali",
    "categoria":"rimborso prestiti",
    "val2015":0
  },
  {
    "voce":"quota capitale di mutui e prestiti",
    "categoria":"rimborso prestiti",
    "val2015":128508755
  },
  {
    "voce":"spese per conto terzi",
    "categoria":"",
    "val2015":232661261
  },
  {
    "voce":"disavanzo di amministrazione",
    "categoria":"",
    "val2015":0
  }
]
```

I tried a for loop with an if statement inside but it is not working.

```
    function count (dataset, chosenCategory) {
    var count = 0;
    for (d in dataset) {
        if (d.categoria==chosenCategory && d.val2015>0) {
                count += 1;
            } else {
                count += 0;
            }

        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried changing "d.value" to "+d.value"?

If they're from a csv file, values are generally loaded as strings, so everything you want to treat as a number needs converted to a number, and the '+' does that.

try it in your console

```
"1">0
false

+"1">0
true
```

PS. You don't need the else condition

Comment: I am actually loading data from a .json file. In my question I used the csv file because I thought it be easier to read. Did not know this could lead to confusion, sorry.. changing the question then

Comment: Moreover even if I take out the d.value condition the loop still does not work. It seems like it is not able to access d.category either: if I run the loop (with a console.log(count) after every addition) I get 19 times "0".

Comment: Is that your actual json file? Just that that appears to be in italian and you're testing for the english language equivalents in your loop.

Comment: it is and in my code i use the italian equivalents.. I just changed the terms to make my question clearer.. anyways even if i test the for loop in the console it does not work (as i said in my previous comment) so i thought there was something wrong in the way I wrote it (although the sintax worked fine for other visualizations I did..)

Comment: the for..in loop is returning indexes as 'd' and not the pieces of data, try --> dataset.forEach (function(d) { ... })

Comment: It worked!! thanks a lot, in the end this is what I did:

`var count=0;
dataset.forEach (function(d) {
if (d.categoria=="funzioni" && d.val2015>0) {
count+=1; 
console.log(count);} 
})`